# Phishing page not detect in localhost

Tags: security, localhost, phishing

Why chrome/firefox not detect localhost phishing?
I'd like to test the bypass, but localhost does not display a phishing script. 
How do I fix this?

Comment: I've no idea what you are trying to explain here

Comment: How to force the browser to detect phishing on localhost?

Comment: how could it? the phishing detector uses centralized lists of known phishing sites to warn you. `http://localhost` is never going to be on those lists.

Comment: Who will phish you on the localhost?

Comment: When I put on phishing 000webhost detect it as a phishing site, but that does not mean that every 000webhost phishing page ... I would not say that this protection for the mass blacklist site...

Comment: Heheheh, I just want to test it on localhost chrome / firefox protection.

Answer (score 0):

Browser or Antivirus will detect your phishing pages based on the content which is hosted. WHen your content is not hosted how will the firefox will detect your phishing page? It does nt. Use some zero fee hosting sites and do host your website and then try. ""your site will be blocked resulting Phishing page"".